# How to select a row through a pivot table

Tags: mysql

I have a database that stores the names of arcade games and the ROM chips they consist of. I have two MySQL tables: `mame_games` and `mame_roms` laid out like this:

```
mame_games
------------
id  | name

mame_roms
------------
id   |  crc
```

and a pivot table (as a ROM can belong to multiple games and a game has multiple ROMs):

```
mame_games_mame_roms
--------------------
id   |   mame_games_id   |   mame_roms_id
```

What I am trying to do is select the game that consists of a particular set of ROMs. For instance, suppose I have three ROMs with CRC values of '12345', '54321' and 'abcde'. I would like to select from `mame_games` the game that is linked to those three ROMs. So, if I have the following data:

```
mame_games
------------
id  | name
1   | gameA
2   | gameB

mame_roms
------------
id   |  crc
1    |  12345
2    |  09876
3    |  54321
4    |  abcde

mame_games_mame_roms
--------------------
id   |   mame_games_id   |   mame_roms_id
1    |   1               |   1
2    |   2               |   2
3    |   1               |   3
4    |   1               |   4
```

I would like to select gameA.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below :

```
select
 distinct g.name
from 
  mame_game g,
  mame_roms r,
  mame_games_mame_roms p
where 
  r.crc in ( '12345', '54321’,'abcde’)
  and r.id = p.mame_roms_id
  and p.mame_game_id = g.id;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. Thank you!